# eclipse treats an old Layout file as a current Layout file

Tags: android, eclipse

There was a layout file with the next editText element:

I changed the name of the **editText** in the XML file from **editText1** to editText2:

```
    <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText2"
```

I saved the change.

Somehow Eclipse in the Java file doesnt recognize this change,
and when I wanted to create the object by

**`EditText myEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);`**
I got a compiler error.

and when I wanted to create the object by

```
EditText myEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

I didn't get any mistake.

I've already saved,refreshed,restarted Eclipse...
Nothing helped.

Comment: have you cleaned the project ?

Comment: Use Android Studio instead Eclipse

Comment: @squiroid Nope..I didn't clean anything.

Comment: Once clean the project and try again.

Comment: @IntelliJ  doesn't help me for this current situation..

Comment: Go to Project → Clean

Comment: @Nag Can you explain please?  Little new for this.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @ squiroid  what does the "clean" option do?  Any danger for the files?

Comment: @Anshul  I posted as you asked.

Comment: Are you creating same object for both editTexts?

Comment: @ Anshul negative. I wanted to show that when I try to create the object with the old name "editText1"  it works,  and when I try to create the object with the new name "editText2"  it fails. These are 2 different times.

Comment: It should work as you're saying. What type of error are you getting in it?

Comment: @ Anshul "editText2" cannot be resolved or is not a field. The amazing thing is that when I change it to editText1 there is no error although in the XML file the name editText1 doesn't exist anymore!

Comment: @ Der  thanks man, but I've done it already. didn't help.